# UISplitViewController detail view controller loads in master view window

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I had a `UISplitViewController` with the following layout, consisting of a single master and detail view controller.

[image]

This worked fine for a basic split view with single views, but I needed to support multiple segues from the `UITableViewController` (Master View) and not load the detail views until data is passed; or else the app will crash because of optional errors.

I tried by having a set up like so;

[image]

This loads a blank `ViewController` as the detail view when the `UISplitViewController` loads, and when a row is selected the I have a detail segue to the other view controllers, which should appear as a detail view in the `UISplitViewController`.

This unfortunately does not work exactly, all the data is passed and loaded without crashes but the detail segues actually load the view controllers within the master view window of the split view not the detail view.

Kind of like this,

[image]

How can I have multiple detail view controllers which are not loaded until initiating a segue from the master view `UITableViewController` and open in the detail window ?

Here's the code from the MasterViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.splitViewController!.delegate = self;
    self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
}


func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the segues were already there then try removing the segues from the master view to the other detail views and recreating them using a detail segue.